# C++ Code displays different, which is unexpected, output in different compilers

Tags: c++, g++, turbo-c++

This is a beginners question.

Following is the C++ code that I was working with

```
int main() {
    int x=5, y=5;
    cout<<x--;
    cout<<",";
    cout<<--x;
    cout<<",";
    cout<<y--<<","<<--y;
    return 0;
}
```

When run in Turbo C++ 3.0 the following is the output displayed by the code:

```
5,3,4,4
```

When compiled with Code::Blocks on Windows (uses MinGW with GCC/G++) the following is the output displayed:

```
5,3,4,3
```

Previously, I have heard that sometimes different compilers behave differently to certain problems, but I don't understand why this result is being displayed. Since logically, as I think, the output should be:

```
5,3,5,3
```

Can you please tell me the reason for such output logically.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Comment: @Casey thanks for pointing me to that question. I didn't find it in search results, but it did explained a lot.

Comment: Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991, so it couldn't possibly have been a C99 compiler.

Comment: @Spire thanks for telling. I'll update the question description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right or wrong output. Your code has undefined behavior and anything is possible.

The reason lies in paragraph 1.9.15 (n3337) of C++ standard (emphasis mine):

> Except where noted, **evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual
>   expressions are unsequenced.** [Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution
>   of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not be
>   performed consistently in different evaluations. —end note ] The value computations of the operands of an
>   operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. **If a side effect on a scalar
>   object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
>   using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undeﬁned.**

In this line

```
cout << y-- << "," << --y;
```

you've introduced two side effects (increments by postfix and prefix, respectively) and two value computations (results of `y--` and `--y`) on a scalar object (`y`) where they are unsequenced. Thus, your program is ill-formed and just about anything is a possible output.

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: Thank you for such good explanation @jork! Now I understand the meaning of 'undefined behavior'.

Answer (score 0):

`cout<<y--<<","<<--y;` is an expression with two unsequenced side effects on `y`, and therefore has undefined behavior.

Comment: @jrok Hey, buddy - who're you calling short?!?

Comment: I see... I should have noticed that both expressions are in same statement.
Anyway, thanks for your help. It's the first time I ever came across such problem.