# Order of outputting with cout output stream

Tags: c++, output, cout

I am trying to run this simple code

```
int a=0;
cout<<a<<a++;
```

but the output is not what I expected

```
10
```

I would expect "00" and a=1, why is the answer different?

Comment: I've answered, but I'm willing to bet that this is a duplicate.

Comment: [Asked just few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772464/c-code-displays-different-which-is-unexpected-output-in-different-compilers/17772778#17772778), same thing basically. Follow the links posted there, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [C++ standard](http://cs.calvin.edu/books/c++/C++Standard-Nov97/expr.html) does not specify an order of execution for subexpressions

> Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual
>     operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the  order
>     in which side effects take place, is unspecified...

Answer (score 3):

And what do you expect?  Or more correctly, you're wrong to
expect anything: you're modifying a variable, and accessing it
for reasons other than determining the value to write, with no
intervening sequence point, so the code has undefined behavior.
It might output "10", it might output "01", or it might output
"42", or even crash.

Comment: You're saying cout << a << a++; is the answer to the universe ?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman Could be.  Undefined behavior might actually be a very good answer to the universe.  (Of course, undefined behavior might also send an email to all of your colleagues, inviting them to drinks down at the pub, on you.  Or send an insulting email to your boss, telling him what you really think of him.  Or generate a bank transfer from your account to that of the compiler writer.)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple... As per my knowledge in C++ order of execution of any statement starts from right... in cout<

Comment: Associativity is right to left for some operators, but not <<.